# Move OneNote file to another OneDrive account

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to move a OneNote notebook from one OneDrive account to another? I have one very large notebook (several thousand pages) and it is going to be tedious manually copying.

I no longer control the domain that the OneDrive account is on so I want to close it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 19):

I just did this myself and found Oesten Nelson's answer helpful. However, there are some details that should be added (I can't comment on the other answer since I'm a fresh user). This was done on Windows 10 with OneNote 2016 for desktop. The mac version doesn't seem to support exporting notebooks.

1. Choose the notebook of interest in OneNote and make sure it's fully synced.
2. File-Export-Export Current Notebook-Notebook package and save it to a local folder which is not on the same OneDrive as you will migrate it to.
3. Close the notebook in OneNote
4. Double-click the saved package from the local folder. When OneNote asks where to save the imported notebook, you change the default suggestion to the same local folder where the exported package is.
5. After it's opened in OneNote, go to File-Share and you will be prompted to put it on OneDrive in order to share it. Just select the OneDrive you're migrating to and the wanted folder, edit name if necessary and click Move.
6. The notebook will be converted to an online notebook and it will turn up as an url shortcut in the local OneDrive directory just as before.
7. Now you should be able to delete the local export/copy in the explorer without trouble, and the notebook is syncing from the new OneDrive instead. On the old OneDrive, you can delete the notebook if wanted/available, but this must be done from the web interface. The notebook can be opened on other devices from the new OneDrive as normally.

It's important to save the temporary local copy in a different location from the final OneDrive location, or else you will risk sync errors when OneNote tries to convert it to a shareable notebook in steps 5/6. I tried it with several notebooks which failed to sync properly. When you wait till the final share-step with placing it in the correct OneDrive folder, the syncing goes without trouble.

Answer (score 4):

For a OneDrive-to-OneDrive migration, I recommend using File-Export-Export Current Notebook, then move it to wherever you need to for the new OneDrive account.  Then, double-click it to open it/unpack it, and finally use File-Share and follow the prompts to re-load it to a OneDrive/Office365 account.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to do, as long as you have access to both accounts.  Here's how:

1) Sync the notebook to a local copy of OneNote by opening it in the
        OneNote client.

2) Open your new OneDrive site in your browser.

3) From
        your local computer's OneNote Notebooks folder, copy the folder
        containing your notebook into the corresponding OneNote Notebooks
        folder in OneDrive.

4) Delete the notebook folder from the OneNote Notebooks folder of the old OneDrive site.

That's all there is to it.   If you use a local client, it may be necessary to delete the local copy of the notebook and resync it from OneDrive - otherwise you can begin using it via OneNote Web App.

Answer (score 3):

I just did the same thing. From my old OneDrive account to my new OneDrive account, via **changing sync options to new OneDrive account**.

The way I just did this and it worked successfully.

1. Sign up for a OneDrive account.
2. Open the OneNote notebook that you wish to transfer. (Slide 1)
3. Click on the notebook tab. (Slide 2)
4. Right-click on the notebook. Choose "Properties". (Slide 3)
5. Click on "Change Location". (Slide 4)
6. Navigate to your OneDrive folder location. (Slide 5)

   **Done**: Slide 6 shows what your OneDrive folder looks like while synced to your OneDrive folder online.

[image]
Click on Image to enlarge (play/pause).

Comment: I tried this. Now Onenote seems to think this is a local file and its not synced using OneNote but file by file using OneDrive. The onenote file appears as folder ine OneDrive instead of the usual OneNote-Link.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, I browsed to my sharepoint site and placed it there.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was drag & drop between the two accounts using that corny Windows client that signs into multiple accounts and still shows the same notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this between a OneDrive "personal" account and one associated with my school.  I'm a Mac user.  What worked for me was:

1. Open the old notebook in the OneNote Mac application
2. Create a new notebook in the new account with the OneNote web interface
3. Open the new notebook in OneNote Mac
4. On the Mac, for each section of the old notebook, select Notebook > Move Section to... and choose the new notebook.
5. Sync and close both notebooks (the old one will be empty, the new one has the contents of the old one).
6. From the old account's OneDrive web interface, you can delete the old empty notebook.

I used two different web browsers to stay logged into the two OneDrive accounts simultaneously.

You say you have thousands of pages—if there are only a few dozen sections it won't take too long.